# Print preview is adding one blank page

Tags: css, print-preview

I can print with my code but from where a blank page is coming in print preview i do not know.
Also, first page should be as per the width and height of div.
Print preview should show only the div with class `.canvasSaveder`.

```
<style>
    /* Style for the canvasSaveder div that holds the image and input fields */
    .canvasSaveder {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%; /* Use percentage width to make it responsive */
        height: 100%; /* Use percentage width to make it responsive */
    }

    /* Style for the image */
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    /* Style for the input fields */
    input {
        position: absolute;
        outline: none;
        background: transparent;
        font-size: 25px;
        border: none;
    }
    .nameA {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        width:63%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 3%;
        top: 30%;
    }
    .nameE {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        width:63%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 3%;
        top: 39%;
    }
    .nationalityE {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        width:23%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 25%;
        top: 49.5%;
    }
    .nationalityA {
        font-size: 23px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: right;
        width:17%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 49%;
        top: 49.5%;
    }
    .department {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        width:53%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 13%;
        top: 58%;
    }
    .title {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        width:53.5%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 12.5%;
        top: 69%;
    }
    .blood {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        width:9%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 24%;
        top: 78%;
    }
    .expiry {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        width:25%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 22%;
        top: 88%;
    }
    .staffno {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: white !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        width:28%;
        height: 8.5%;
        left: 71%;
        top: 90%;
    }
    .photo {
        width: 28%;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute; /* Change the position to absolute */
        right: 1%; /* Adjust the right property to position the image from the right edge */
        top: 40%;
    }
    @media print {
        body * {
            visibility: hidden;
        }


        .canvasSaveder {
            visibility: visible;
            position: relative;
            color: white !important;
page-break-after: always !important;
        }

        /* Show the image and input fields inside .canvasSaveder */
        .canvasSaveder img,
        .canvasSaveder input {
            visibility: visible;
        }
        .staffno {
            background-color: transparent;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: yellow !important; /* Change color to white */
        }
    }
</style>

<div class="canvasSaveder">
    <img src="images/kacid.jpg" alt="Staff ID Image">
    <!-- Position input fields over the image with percentage-based margins -->
    <input id="charA" type="text" name="aname"
    value="<?php echo $aname; ?>" class="resizeME nameA">
    <input id="charE" type="text" name="ename"
    value="<?php echo $ename; ?>" class="resizeME nameE">
    <input id="natE" type="text" name="enationality"
    value="<?php echo $cename; ?>" class="resizeME nationalityE">
    <input id="natA" type="text" name="anationality"
    value="<?php echo $caname; ?>" class="resizeME nationalityA">
    <input id="department" type="text" name="department"
    value="<?php echo $dename; ?>" class="resizeME department">
    <input id="title" type="text" name="title"
    value="<?php echo $tename; ?>" class="resizeME title">
    <input id="blood" type="text" name="blood"
    value="<?php echo $blename; ?>" class="resizeME blood">
    <input id="date" type="text" name="expiry"
    class="resizeME expiry" value="<?php echo $current_date; ?>">
    <input id="staffnos" type="text" name="staffno"
    class="resizeME staffno" value="<?php echo $staffno; ?>">
    <span id="photo">
    <img src="images/employees/empPhotos/30546.jpg" class="photo">
    <span>
</div>
    
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <button type="button" onclick="printStaffID()">Print Staff ID</button>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black;">

<script>
    function printStaffID() {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: visibility: hidden still saves space for the elements involved.

Answer (score 0):

`visibility: hidden` still keeps the space for the related elements.

This code has `display: none` for those element that are not wanted in the print:

```
  body *:not(.canvasSaveder):not(.canvasSaveder img):not(.canvasSaveder input) {
      display: none;
      )
```

```html
<style>
    /* Style for the canvasSaveder div that holds the image and input fields */
  
  .canvasSaveder {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* Use percentage width to make it responsive */
    height: 100%;
    /* Use percentage width to make it responsive */
  }
  /* Style for the image */
  
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  /* Style for the input fields */
  
  input {
    position: absolute;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 25px;
    border: none;
  }
  
  .nameA {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 63%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 3%;
    top: 30%;
  }
  
  .nameE {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 63%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 3%;
    top: 39%;
  }
  
  .nationalityE {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    width: 23%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 25%;
    top: 49.5%;
  }
  
  .nationalityA {
    font-size: 23px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    width: 17%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 49%;
    top: 49.5%;
  }
  
  .department {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    width: 53%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 13%;
    top: 58%;
  }
  
  .title {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    width: 53.5%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 12.5%;
    top: 69%;
  }
  
  .blood {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    width: 9%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 24%;
    top: 78%;
  }
  
  .expiry {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 22%;
    top: 88%;
  }
  
  .staffno {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 28%;
    height: 8.5%;
    left: 71%;
    top: 90%;
  }
  
  .photo {
    width: 28%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    /* Change the position to absolute */
    right: 1%;
    /* Adjust the right property to position the image from the right edge */
    top: 40%;
  }
  
  @media print {

  body *:not(.canvasSaveder):not(.canvasSaveder img):not(.canvasSaveder input) {
      display: none;
      )
     .canvasSaveder {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        color: white !important;
        page-break-after: always !important;
      }
      /* Show the image and input fields inside .canvasSaveder */
      .canvasSaveder img,
      .canvasSaveder input {
        visibility: visible;
      }
      .staffno {
        background-color: transparent;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: yellow !important;
        /* Change color to white */
      }
    }
</style>

<div class="canvasSaveder">
  <img src="images/kacid.jpg" alt="Staff ID Image">
  <!-- Position input fields over the image with percentage-based margins -->
  <input id="charA" type="text" name="aname" value="<?php echo $aname; ?>" class="resizeME nameA">
  <input id="charE" type="text" name="ename" value="<?php echo $ename; ?>" class="resizeME nameE">
  <input id="natE" type="text" name="enationality" value="<?php echo $cename; ?>" class="resizeME nationalityE">
  <input id="natA" type="text" name="anationality" value="<?php echo $caname; ?>" class="resizeME nationalityA">
  <input id="department" type="text" name="department" value="<?php echo $dename; ?>" class="resizeME department">
  <input id="title" type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $tename; ?>" class="resizeME title">
  <input id="blood" type="text" name="blood" value="<?php echo $blename; ?>" class="resizeME blood">
  <input id="date" type="text" name="expiry" class="resizeME expiry" value="<?php echo $current_date; ?>">
  <input id="staffnos" type="text" name="staffno" class="resizeME staffno" value="<?php echo $staffno; ?>">
  <span id="photo">
    <img src="images/employees/empPhotos/30546.jpg" class="photo">
    <span>
</div>
    
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <button type="button" onclick="printStaffID()">Print Staff ID</button>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black;">

<script>
    function printStaffID() {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

ADDITION: SO snippet is not very happy with this so here is the naked code, copy to run on your browser.

```
<style>
    /* Style for the canvasSaveder div that holds the image and input fields */
    .canvasSaveder {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%; /* Use percentage width to make it responsive */
        height: 100%; /* Use percentage width to make it responsive */
    }

    /* Style for the image */
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    /* Style for the input fields */
    input {
        position: absolute;
        outline: none;
        background: transparent;
        font-size: 25px;
        border: none;
    }
    .nameA {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        width:63%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 3%;
        top: 30%;
    }
    .nameE {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        width:63%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 3%;
        top: 39%;
    }
    .nationalityE {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        width:23%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 25%;
        top: 49.5%;
    }
    .nationalityA {
        font-size: 23px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: right;
        width:17%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 49%;
        top: 49.5%;
    }
    .department {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        width:53%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 13%;
        top: 58%;
    }
    .title {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        width:53.5%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 12.5%;
        top: 69%;
    }
    .blood {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        width:9%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 24%;
        top: 78%;
    }
    .expiry {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        width:25%;
        height: 8%;
        left: 22%;
        top: 88%;
    }
    .staffno {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: white !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        width:28%;
        height: 8.5%;
        left: 71%;
        top: 90%;
    }
    .photo {
        width: 28%;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute; /* Change the position to absolute */
        right: 1%; /* Adjust the right property to position the image from the right edge */
        top: 40%;
    }
    @media print {
        rbody * {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        body *:not(.canvasSaveder):not(.canvasSaveder img):not(.canvasSaveder input) { display: none;)

        .canvasSaveder {
            visibility: visible;
            position: relative;
            color: white !important;
page-break-after: always !important;
        }

        /* Show the image and input fields inside .canvasSaveder */
        .canvasSaveder img,
        .canvasSaveder input {
            visibility: visible;
        }
        .staffno {
            background-color: transparent;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: yellow !important; /* Change color to white */
        }
    }
</style>

<div class="canvasSaveder">
    <img src="images/kacid.jpg" alt="Staff ID Image">
    <!-- Position input fields over the image with percentage-based margins -->
    <input id="charA" type="text" name="aname"
    value="aname" class="resizeME nameA">
    <input id="charE" type="text" name="ename"
    value="ename" class="resizeME nameE">
    <input id="natE" type="text" name="enationality"
    value="cename" class="resizeME nationalityE">
    <input id="natA" type="text" name="anationality"
    value="caname" class="resizeME nationalityA">
    <input id="department" type="text" name="department"
    value="dename" class="resizeME department">
    <input id="title" type="text" name="title"
    value="tename" class="resizeME title">
    <input id="blood" type="text" name="blood"
    value="blename" class="resizeME blood">
    <input id="date" type="text" name="expiry"
    class="resizeME expiry" value="current_dat">
    <input id="staffnos" type="text" name="staffno"
    class="resizeME staffno" value="staffno">
    <span id="photo">
    <img src="images/employees/empPhotos/30546.jpg" class="photo">
    <span>
</div>
    
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <button type="button" onclick="printStaffID()">Print Staff ID</button>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black;">

<script>
    function printStaffID() {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: .canvasSaveder should be shown only and whatever inside this div by your code nothing is shown in print preview

Comment: Hi,, yes it is. Maybe the problem is you are running it as an SO snippet whereas the code needs to be run via your PHP etc system as it stands. I'll create it as ordinary code rather than a snippet so it's easier to try out

Comment: It's OK for me (as actual code, not an SO snippet). I'm on Edge/Chrome Windows 10. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: sorry for delay i was out. im using EDGE / FIREFOX both does not show anything in print preview

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what to suggest - how are you running the code (the code I added, not the snippet)? I'm running it locally from Edge and it's fine, no extra page.

Comment: no extra page but empty i cannot see anything, nothing is showing up .canvasSaveder should be shown

Comment: It shows for me (with of course those dummy values I put in. Very odd. Good luck in tracking the problem down.